# Making requests through tor, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError Errno 61: Connection Refused

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, tor

I'm trying to make a simple request to a whatsmyip site while connected to tor but no matter what I try I continue to get this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /get (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x1018a7438>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

I've looked at a lot of posts on here with similar issues but I can't seem to find a fix that works.

This is the current code but I've tried multiple ways and its the same error every time:

```
import requests

def main():
    proxies = {
            'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
            'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
    }
    r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get', proxies=proxies)
    print(r.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the error says `Max retries exceeded with url:`, so possibly could be too many requests has been made from the tor exit nodes ip. Attempt to do it with a new Tor identity and see if that works.

If you wanted to you could catch the exception and put it in a loop to attempt every number of seconds, but this may lead to that ip address being refused by the server for longer.